# nullable foreign keys versus common parent key

Tags: sql, t-sql

In a scenario where we have customers, vendors, & branches which all have common attributes such as an address, which is a better solution and why?

Solution 1:

- Customer table
- Vendor table
- Branch table
- Address table with nullable foreign keys for CustomerID, VendorID, BranchID

Solution 2:

- Entity table
- Customer table with EntityID
- Vendor table with EntityID
- Branch table with EntityID
- Address table with EntityID and a EntityType flag of 'C', 'V', or 'B'

Solution 3 (suggested by AJC):

- Customer table
- Vendor table
- Branch table
- Address table
- CustomerAddress xref table between Customer and Address
- VendorAddress xref table between Vendor and Address
- BranchAddress xref table between Branch and Address

Solution 4 (suggested by 9000)

- Customer table
- Vendor table
- Branch table
- CustomerAddress with FK to Customer
- VendorAddress with FK to Vendor
- BranchAddress with FK to Branch
- vwAddress which UNION ALLs each of the above address tables, and includes a type flag ('B','C','V')

Notes:

Each customer, vendor, or branch could have multiple addresses, but should have at least one.

If an "entity" is both a customer and a vendor, it could have separate addresses for each role.

Would like to know if a customer is also a vendor.

Comment: I don't wish to get too philosophical but what do you consider an 'address' to be? Is it an attribute of an entity? e.g. "a Customer can be 'addressed' using this Address value". Or is it an entity in its own right with which other entities, perhaps of different types, may have a relationship? e.g. "this address is in a 'branch address' relationship with these Branches and in a 'customer address' relationship with this Customer."

Comment: Someone here at work suggested an "entity" model (i.e. Solution 2) and I thought it might help simplify the situation where addresses (and other child tables common to all three entities) needed to link to all three.  An entity that is both a customer and a vendor can have different addresses in each role.  The above scenario is a simplification, but the more complex model includes shipping addresses, billing addresses, and temporary addresses.

Comment: But are the **addresses** entities? e.g. do you have a business need be able to tell if two customers have the same address?

Comment: It depends on how complex it makes it.  It would be nice to deduplicate addresses, but at the same time, if one customer changes an address, we don't want to globally change the address for every customer, vendor or branch that happens to have the same address.   I guess the answer would be "No."

Comment: In which case, @9000's answer sounds spot on to me :)

Comment: Thank you to AJC, 9000, & onedaywhen for excellent responses.  Both AJC's and 9000's answers made it clear that I need to normalize more.  Both answers are valid.  AJC responded first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C) None of the above.

The correct way to do it would be to have an Address Table and a CustomerAddress, VendorAddress and BranchAddress respectively to join each C V B entity with one or many addresses.

For attributes that are one-to-one, obviously there is no need for the extra tables, you just add the Id to the main table (AddressId)...

Comment: This is a good straightforward design that I considered initially (or at least close to it) ... but I wanted to avoid the extra join if possible.  In retrospect, my original solutions are no simpler.

Comment: @Korey Your are right, this design does require more tables and joins, however they are there for a reason other than make thing complicated. It will also make things simpler in the long run and make your design more scalable and future proof. Plus help you design better code around it.

Comment: It seems like our design team has had an aversion to table sprawl, which it seems like happens whenever you have many cross-reference tables.  I realize that this keeps the purpose of each table simple, and probably ends up avoiding more problems.

Comment: @Korey well, ultimately its all about your own experience... Who am I to say what will work better for you. It is a fine line between good design and over-design. Sometimes it might do more harm if you can't determine properly what should and should not be normalized. But only the person who know how the entire system will interact can make those kind of decisions...

Answer (score 3):

(This is basically what @AJC said, just explained.)

Solution 1 potentially allows to assign the same address to up to three entities of different kinds. Unless the latter is exactly your intention, avoid this solution.

Solution 2 allows to potentially assign a 'B' type address to a Customer, etc. Probably this is also not what you want.

As far as I understand your intention, you need to be able to assign multiple addresses to an entity, but not the other way around.

Create an address table per entity kind: `CustomerAddress` with FK referring to `Customer`, `VendorAddress` with FK to `Vendor`, etc. Besides strict referential integrity and impossibility to assign an address of incorrect type, this buys you an ability to extend each type of address with extra fields that only make sense for it.

To query all addresses more easily, you can create a view `Address`, which would include common fields and a type flag ('B', 'C', 'V') to see what kind of address is this.

Comment: I don't think your answer was exactly the same as AJC's.  I added both to my question.

Comment: I don't expect the addresses to have extra fields that apply to just one type of "entity", beyond any foreign keys.

Comment: Actually that is not quite what I said... In my suggestion **Address** is not a view but a table, holding all addresses. However, @Korey got the idea for both suggestions and they are as he reflects them in the edit to his post.